# Approximating Number of members in a set after union

Tags: combinatorics

I am not sure whether it is possible to this or not, but what I am trying to do is calculate the number of members in a set union (of large size N) without actually forming the set physically.

For instance, the generic set union formula for 3 sets is4

p(A+B+C) = p(A) + p(B) + p(C) - p(A.B) - p(B.C) - p (A.C) + p(A.B.C)

The issue with calculating all these values are the exponential amount of work for adding each new set. When I want to do it for a large number of set's (say N) , the work is almost N^N (highly exponential) and would never complete.

Is there a way to approximate the union of such sets? Are there some specific property in sets which can help me do the approximation? 
I am able to calculate each of the values to the right (but cant calculate all of them due to exponential number of terms) so can I use these to get an approximation?

Any help is appreciated